# Rails help rewriting rails randomize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I rewrite this?

```
@bannerkat = Konkurrancer.where("kategori_id = '#{@kategor}'").order('rand()').first
```

To something like this `@banner = Konkurrancer.all[rand(Konkurrancer.all.size)]`

I have tried this:

```
@bannerkat = Konkurrancer.all[rand(Konkurrancer.where("kategori_id = '#{@kategor}'"))]
```

And how do I prevent a SQL injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
@items= Konkurrancer.where("kategori_id = '#{@kategor}'")
@random_item = @items[rand(@items.size)]
```

Comment: Private method called - Method missing

Comment: sorry my bad, thats deperacted in rails 3. Updated answer

Comment: This way gets the ENTIRE COLLECTION from the DB!

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL `ORDER BY rand()` is crazy slow. Try this instead: `Konkurrancer.first :offset => ( Konkurrancer.count * rand ).to_i`